# CRM 2011/2013 Workflow or Plugin gives "Access Denied. Reference number for administrators or support"

Tags: plugins, crm

since i dint found any forum here goes the solution for this problem, this goes for people how work with also ADXSTUDIO, ADXSTUDIO have several plugins and workflows that is registed as to run as Calling User, and for so, we sometimes need to change this permissions.

"Access Denied. Reference number for administrators or support: #xxxxxx"

```
Plugin Trace:

[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.CreateEntity]
[CreateStep1: Create Record as Activity]


    [Adxstudio.Xrm.Plugins.Productivity: Adxstudio.Xrm.Plugins.Productivity.Utilities.IdentifierRequestPlugin]
    [e0ebe1fa-b46e-e111-a0dc-00155d03a708: Adxstudio.Xrm.Plugins.Productivity.Utilities.IdentifierRequestPlugin: Create of adx_identifierrequest]




Error Message:

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Access Denied. Reference number for administrators or support: #536DBC1EDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147187707</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Access Denied. Reference number for administrators or support: #536DBC1E</Message>
  <Timestamp>2014-05-01T14:35:38.9130605Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.CreateEntity]
[CreateStep1: Create Record as Activity]


    [Adxstudio.Xrm.Plugins.Productivity: Adxstudio.Xrm.Plugins.Productivity.Utilities.IdentifierRequestPlugin]
    [e0ebe1fa-b46e-e111-a0dc-00155d03a708: Adxstudio.Xrm.Plugins.Productivity.Utilities.IdentifierRequestPlugin: Create of adx_identifierrequest]

    </TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Create(Entity entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.CreateCore(Entity entity)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateInternal>b__0(IOrganizationService sdkService)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ActivityServiceBase.ExecuteInTransactedContext(ActivityDelegate activityDelegate)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.CreateInternal(Entity entity, String StepId)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.ExecuteInternal(ActivityContext executionContext, CreateEntity createEntity)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.CreateActivityService.Execute(ActivityContext executionContext, CreateEntity createEntity)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution (This works for any plugin or workflow where gives the access error) :

[image]